# Prove if infinite product of $f(x)$ is $0$ then so is infinite product of $f(x\varphi)$

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

Prove or disprove that if $$\prod\limits_{x=2}^{\infty} f(x)=0$$ and $f(x)\neq0$ for any $x\geq0$ then $$\prod\limits_{x=2}^{\infty} f(x\varphi)=0$$ for any constant $\varphi\geq2$

This seems true but I'm not quite sure how to prove it since the constant is inside a function f.

Comment: Question : What means for you the product here ? Is everything natural number ?

Comment: Yes x can only be a natural number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider any continuous function defined over $\mathbb{N}$ by
$$f(n)=\cases{\frac12&$n$ odd\\1&$n$ even}$$
An explicit example is given by
$$f(x)=\frac{3+\cos{(\pi x)}}4$$
Then we have
$$\prod_{x=2}^\infty f(x)=0$$
But
$$\prod_{x=2}^\infty f(2x)=1$$

Comment: What does "continuous" have to do with it?

Comment: Hi, do you think this would still be false if f(x) was strictly decreasing?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Just trying to cover all my bases here.

Answer (score 0):

Not really: you can consider your favourite function $f$ such that $f(n)=1-\frac1n$ for all odd $n\in \Bbb N$ and $f(n)=1-2^{-n-1}$ for all even $n\in\Bbb N$. Then clearly $\prod_n f(n)$ diverges to $0$, whereas $\prod_n f(2n)$ converges to a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Let is say we want to disprove it.  Then we need a $\varphi$ for which this product is not zero.  One way to obtain that is for $f$ to be $1$ at all integer multiples of $\varphi$.  So let's decide that $\varphi = 2$ and $f$ is $1$ for all even integers.  Then we need the values of $f$ on odd integers to give $0$ in the first product.  One way is to have $f(\text{odd}) = 1/\text{odd}$.  Sharpening that up, we obtain...

This is false as written.  Let
$$  f(x) = \begin{cases}1 ,& \text{$x$ is an even integer }  \\ 1/x ,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  $$

Then $\prod_{x=2}^\infty f(x) = 0$, but $\prod_{x=2}^\infty f(2x) = 1$.  In fact, for any $\varphi \geq 2$ an even integer, $\prod_{x=2}^\infty f(\varphi x) = 1$.